# Notepad++ adding commas to the end of words

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to add commas to the end of words but the problem is some of the words have more than one word in it for example:

> Accent Colors
>   Anti-Social Protagonist

I have a list of the words i would like commas behind (5,000 words).

I'll be adding a small list of words to notepad++ each time and its a pain to put a comma behind each one.

So for example:

> Appearance Different from Personality Art Students Youkai 14th Century Afraid of Being Hated

would turn into

> Appearance Different from Personality, Art Students, Youkai, 14th Century, Afraid of Being Hated,

Comment: Do I understand correctly: you have two files, 1) a definitive list of the group of words, separated by newlines and 2) a long list of words, separated by space, that should be grouped according to document #1? Why do you need everything in one line anyway?

Comment: @slhck I paste a group of words into notepad++ put commas at the end of them and than move them to a separate program, it is a different set of words each time but all the word are from a list.

I want to be able to run something so that it will automatically put a comma behind the words instead of me having to do it manually.

i was originally going to use macros but inputting 10,000 different commands would be tiring and im not sure if a macro can record that much.

Comment: I don't know how to achieve this kind of file-based lookup with Notepad++. It's not a regex functionality anyway, rather something you'd have to script. But I don't know if you need to use this particular software, or if anything else would also do the job? I guess I'd write a small script (e.g., Python) that takes a number of words as input, processes it based on the “master list”, then outputs the words with commas included. You can pipe your clipboard contents into that script, and pipe its output back into the clipboard.

Comment: @slhck Something like this would work great, I'm useless when it comes to python though.

Do you know any way i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Using **Replace** dialog:

- Find what: `\b(word1|word2|word3)\b`
- Replace with: `\1,`
- Search mode: Regular Expression

Limitation: "Find what" can have up to 2000 characters, so you will need more passes, for example doing your 5000 words in 25 groups of 200.